# Blockfrost, GrapgQL or any API for cardano help, working with javascript

Tags: api, blockfrost, cardano-graphql, javascript

I am building an MERN stack app cardano dex tool, I want to use Blockfrost.

I have installed the [SDK](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js) in Node.js backend, but there are only very few examples on how to get any kind of data from it.

The [Blockfrost documentation](https://docs.blockfrost.io/) gives more info and I know how to use it with fetch, but only url based and don't know how to implement QUERY PARAMETERS into the url request. Here is an example.

```
function getAssets(){
        fetch(`https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets`,{
            headers: {
                "project_id":'API KEY'
            },
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{console.log(data)})
    }
    getAssets()
```

If there is someone that could explain me a bit how to start using Blockfrost the proper way with a Node.js backend and basically get any kind of information.

Or maybe there is a better solution to get all data from the Cardano network, I have an relay node running with GraphQL, but getting data from that is very difficult if you just starting to use it and I don't know if it will keep working after the Alonzo fork.

Please someone that can help me pointing the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Blockfrost SDK is pretty straight forward, [as in this example](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js/blob/master/examples/api.ts):

```
import { BlockFrostAPI } from '../src/index';

async function run() {
  const API = new BlockFrostAPI({
    projectId: 'YOUR API KEY HERE', // see: https://blockfrost.io
  });

  try {
    const latestBlock = await API.blocksLatest();
    const latestEpoch = await API.epochsLatest();
    const health = await API.health();
    const address = await API.addresses(
      'addr1qxqs59lphg8g6qndelq8xwqn60ag3aeyfcp33c2kdp46a09re5df3pzwwmyq946axfcejy5n4x0y99wqpgtp2gd0k09qsgy6pz',
    );

    console.log('address', address);
    console.log('latestEpoch', latestEpoch);
    console.log('latestBlock', latestBlock);
    console.log('health', health);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
  }
}

run();
```

Basically you can use any of Blockfrost endpoints in the SDK as well, check out [the list of available calls](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js/wiki/BlockFrostAPI.md). I recommend you using an IDE such as [codium](https://vscodium.com/) as it will autofill these as you code.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. Well you are right the wiki you show is very clear. Somehow I missed the right menu to get more specific info.